# Expected area of triangle inscribed in a circle

Tags: geometric-probability

On  a  unit  circle , BC  is  a  chord  with  length  4/π . Point  A  is  picked   randomly at  its circumference .
Find  the  expected  area  of  △  ABC .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For easy reference let chord BC sits in the lower portion of the unit circle.  It lies horizontally making angle $2\phi$ at the centre of the circle symmetric to the y axis.

Then the perpendicular distance of the chord from the centre is $D = \sqrt{(1 - (\frac{2}{\pi})^2}$ and $sin\phi = \frac{2}{\pi}$

Let the line joining A and the centre makes an angle $\theta$ with the x axis, then

For $\theta$ between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$,

$$Area = \frac{1}{2}\frac{4}{\pi}(sin\theta + D)$$

For $\theta$ between  $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2} - \phi$

$$Area = \frac{1}{2}\frac{4}{\pi}(D - sin\theta)$$

For $\theta$ between $\frac{\pi}{2} - \phi$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$

$$Area = \frac{1}{2}\frac{4}{\pi}(sin\theta - D)$$

Hence the average area is

$$\frac{4}{2\pi^2}(\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(sin\theta + D)d\theta + \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2} - \phi}(D - sin\theta)d\theta + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2} - \phi}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(sin\theta - D)d\theta)$$

$$= \frac{2}{\pi^2}(\frac{2}{\pi} + D\pi - 2D\phi + sin\phi) = 0.533$$

I managed to borrow a PC and use 1000 random points and the result is around 5,1 which is very close to the calculation.

Also if the area is $\frac{3}{2\pi}$, I have used trial and error to find x to be about 1.54 which is your expected answer.

Comment: Thanks  for  your reply .You got a result of about 0.7 sq.unit . Will  you  please  check the result with simulation . If  they 
match then I will  accept the result .

Comment: We can estimate the area for those triangles above the chord.  As D is 0.77 and the chord length is 1.27.  The simple average height of these triangles is (1+0.77)/2 = 0.885.  Therefore the area is 1/2. x 0.885 x 1.27 = 0.562.  Similarly the simple area average is 1/2 x 0.115 x 1.27 = 0.07 for those triangles below the chord.  Since the % of height over 0.885 is higher, the answer of 0.7 is reasonable.

Comment: :Thanks again . If  the  question  is  changed  to  :  The  length of  chord  BC = x units , while A  is  picked  randomly .
If  the expected  area of △ ABC  = 3/ 2π (about 0.477 sq.un) , then  what is the value of  x ?

Comment: In fact the formula in terms of D and phi is 1/(pi^2) x (4sinphi + 2piD). Now D = \sqrt(1-x^2/4) and sin phi = x/2. Then put this into the area formula we have x = 1.99. That means the chord is almost the diameter.  Please see if this is what you expect.

Comment: I  got  an  answer of about  1.53  elsewhere . Is it   useful  to  use  simulation  to  clarify ?

Comment: I have checked the working to arrive at the above formula.  Also I have checked the calculation to get the 1.99.  In fact I do not have a computer only an iPad so that I cannot do any simulation.  Hence please run a simulation to clarify.  If I had a PC I would use Excel to generate a lot of points on the circle and use it to calculate the area.  Sorry I cannot help in the simulation.

Comment: I have checked again the above and found that I have allowed negative area.  I have then edited the answer.  Sorry for the mistake I have made.

Comment: Thanks  again ! I  can't  do  the  simulation  myself  because  I  don't  know ! 
In  fact  the  aim  of  this  question is  to  find  whether  there  is  a  relation  between  the  expected  length  of  one  side  ( chord )  with  the  expected  area  of  △  inscribed  in  a  unit  circle .(which  can  be  found  to  be  3/ 2π  . If  3  points  are  picked  randomly , the  circumference  will  be  split  into  3  arcs . The  expected  length  of  each  arc  should  be  2π /3  .( which  =  1/  (  3/ 2π ) ) . How  to  find  the  expected  length  of  each  chord of  the  △  ?

Comment: Please note that I have edited the answer to show the correct one.  If you have Excel you can set up a spreadsheet to do a simulation using the function =rand() which returns a random number 0 and 1.  However in order to account for negative y value you have to set up a second column with function =randbetween(-1,1) which will return the number -1, 0 or 1.  You can use a third column to get the product of the first 2 columns to give you a random y value to be used in a formula for the area in term of y.  You can copy the 4 cells and paste downward as many as you want.  I did copy 1000 sets.

Comment: For you last question when the arc length is known we can calculate the chord length.  In this case 1x\phi = 2\pi/3 = phi = 2pi/3.  Chord length = 2rsinphi = 2sin(2pi/3)= sqrt(3)=1.732.

Comment: I just found that you can use the formula =randbetween(-10000,10000)/10000 under the column for y value to calculate areas for simulation.  This formula returns random number between -1 and 1 directly.  This is simpler than I suggested earlier on.

Comment: Thanks  much  for  your  enthusiasm ! For the  length  of 
the  chord I  don't  mean  the  length  of  the  chord  
corresponding  to  the  arc  with  expected  length . In  
fact  their  expected  lengths  should  be  calculated  
separately .Please  refer  to  my  another  question  " expected 
lengths " which  has  just  been  closed .